# Django, ManyToManyField - ProgrammingError: relation foo_bar does not exist. Recognized in migrations, though relation is never created

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-models

In this case, "foo_bar" is actually "links_userprofile_favorite_feeds".

The problem is, when I go into manage.py shell:

## manage.py shell

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from feeds.models import feed
p = User.objects.get(username='myuser')
p.save()
q = Feed.objects.get(title='myfeed')
q.save()
p.userprofile.favorite_feed.add(q)
```

I get

## the error:

```
ProgrammingError: relation "links_userprofile_favorite_feeds" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."links_userprofile_favorite_feeds"."feed_id" FROM "links_use...
```

Here are the relevant files and traceback:

#### links.models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploaded_files/")  
    favorite_feeds = models.ManyToManyField(Feed)
```

#### feeds.models.py

```
class Feed(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=25)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            #Newly created object, so set slug
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        super(Feed,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)
```

The relation seems to be present in the migration, but `manage.py syncdb, manage.py makemigrations, manage.py migrate`, all do not work (no migrations to apply).

Can anyone help? I am wanting to create the relation `"links_userprofile_favorite_feeds."`

Comment: Its clearly a database issue, so u have either not created the migration, or have not migration folder in the app directory or the app isn't registered at INSTALLED_APP. and don't use syncdb.

Comment: @ruddra The migration is shown in the migration file above. All necessary apps have been installed. Why shouldn't I use syncdb?

Comment: [syncdb has been deprecated and replaced by migrate](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releases/1.7.html#schema-migrations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.

For those with this problem in the future:

1. Delete all links_* tables from the database (app was called 'links')
2. Delete all migrations for the 'links' app by doing:

   ```
   from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
   MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.filter(app='links').delete()
   ```
3. Migrated forward with `manage.py migrate`